# Really slow query used to be really fast. Explain shows rows=1 on local backup but rows=2287359 on server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-like, sql-execution-plan

I check for spam every now and then using "select * from posts where post like '%http://%' order by id desc limit 10" and searching a few other keywords. Lately the select is impossibly slow.

```
mysql> explain select * from posts where reply like "%http://%" order by id desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts     | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 2287347 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On my netbook with 1 gig ram the only difference is it shows the "ROWS" column as being 1. There is only 1.3 mil posts in my netbook. The server has like 6 gigs ram and a fast processor. What should I optimize so it's not horribly slow. Recently I added an index to search by userId, which I'm not sure was a smart choice, but I added it to the backup and production server both a little before this issue started happening. I'd imagine it's related to it not being able to sort in ram due to a missed tweak?

It also seems to be slow when I do stuff like "delete from posts where threadId=X", dunno if related.

Comment: Can you show the CREATE statement for your table (including indexes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE reply LIKE "%http://%" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Due to the wild cards on both sides of the `http://`, MySQL will can not use an index on `reply` to quickly find what you're looking for. Moreover, since you're asking for the one with the largest `id`, MySQL will have to pull all results to make sure that you have the one with the largest `id'.

Depending how much of the data of the `posts` table is made up of the `reply`, it might be worthwhile to add a compound index on `(id, reply)`, and change the query to something like

`SELECT id FROM posts WHERE reply LIKE "%http://%" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

(which will have an index only execution), then join to the posts table or retrive the posts using the retrived `id`s. If the query has `index only execution`, and the index fits in memory **and** is already in memory (due to normal use or by intentionality warming it up), you could potentially speed up the query execution.

Having said all that, if identical queries on two identical servers with identical data are giving different execution plans and execution times, it might be time to `OPTIMIZE TABLE posts` to refresh the index statistics and/or defragment the table. If you have recently been adding/removing indexes, things might have gotten astray.  Moreover, if the the data is fragmented, when it's pulling rows in PRIMARY KEY order, it could be jumping all over the disk to retrieve the data.

With respect to `DELETE FROM posts WHERE threadId=X`, it should be fine as long as there is an index on `threadId`.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes won't be used if you start your search comparison with a "%". You problem is with

```
where reply like "%http://%"
```

As confirmed by your explain, no indexes are used. The speed difference may be due to caching.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of indexes do you have on your table(s)?  A good rule of thumb is to have an index on the columns that appear most often in your WHERE clause.  If you do not have an index on your threadId column, your last query will be a lot slower than if you did.

Your first query (select * from posts where post like '%http://%' will be slow simply due to the "like" in the query.  I would suggest filtering your query with another WHERE clause - perhaps by date (which is hopefully indexed):

```
select * from posts where postdate > 'SOMEDATE' and post like '%http://%'
```

Comment: why 'anywhere' LIKE is bad: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: I mean, in the explain query the rows shows 2287347 while in the explain for the backup it shows rows=1. In both I use "limit 1" but for some reason on the server it's loading everything or searching everything. The query used to be fast. order by ID desc I believe is faster because usually it doesn't have to sort when it's a primary key (I believe, not sure!).

Comment: can you try FORCE INDEX ? http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/   ;   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you write an after-insert trigger that examines the text looking for substring 'http://' and either flags the current record or writes out its id to a SPAM table?  As @brent said, indexes are not used for "contains substring" searches.